# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error / WINDOWS SERVER 2016

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, windows-server-2012, vps

compre un servidor vps para alojar un script desarrollado con laravel, nunca habia usado un VPS y cuando subi el proyecto e intente abrirlo me arrojo el siguiente error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data 
for the page is invalid.
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal o que debo configurar para que laravel se ejecute con normalidad en windows Server

Comment: ¿Has instalado el módulo de PHP en el IIS?

Comment: si! lei un poco pero segun es el modulo de redireccion, mas no se usarlo bien

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: Cuando lo desplegaste en el vps instalaste las dependencias de composer? es decir dentro del directorio principal del proyecto en laravel colocaste "composer install"

Comment: lo he hecho y aun asi veo el error, me di cuenta que la ruta no la respeta y cambio de www.example.com/install a www.example.com/public/install, si ingreso asi si funciona

Answer (score 0):

No se que versión de laravel estás usando pero el error es simple estás apuntando mal a la carpeta. La estructura es distinta a tu entorno de desarrollo, hay un nivel más arriba.

Debes editar el archivo index.php y añadir un nivel hacia tu carpeta public con ../ en los requires que aparezcan.